# Cannot connect to ec2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I've created a new ec2 instance based on the php cloudformatino image ami-6fc2f61b and attached my existing key to it. Security group allows ssh and http. Yet, I'm unable to connect:

```
$ ssh -v -i /cygdrive/c/data/copy/pk.pem ec2_user@host
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Connecting to host [46.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/data/copy/pk.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /cygdrive/c/data/copy/pk.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 44:xx:xx:xx
debug1: Host 'host' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/a25058/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /cygdrive/c/data/copy/pk.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What could be possible causes for this?

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved:
I used the wrong user name. Trying to login as root shows the following error:

```
Please login as the ec2-user user rather than root user.
```

Apparently the user naming convention is not consistent amongst even the Amazon AMIs- some use ec2_user, some ec2-user.